# AudioJS, jQuery Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, audiojs

I know there are similar questions, but I could not find one explaining what I am trying to do.

At one of the events I will be working, the MC will need to play music from his browser (it has been set up like that to update all live schedules).

The problem that I have is I get the `Not allowed to load local resource` error when I try to load the audio file from the local drive.

The reason I am trying to load the file from the local drive is for in case the network fails or something happens to the local server, then the event can still continue.

I have read that Chrome gives this error for privacy and security reasons, but Firefox does not load the file and gives no error for doing so.

Is there a browser where this will be possible or is there a way to change browser settings to allow this?

I have tried using the Flash settings to add the file's location as a trusted location, I am however unable to find a flash settings that says `"Load from local disk (only)"`.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I am using the AudioJS plugin to play the music through the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to load files from the local machine for security reasons. Imagine what I could read from your machine if it was >:D

You have to run your code on a web server, and also host the file there. You can easily install IIS if you're on Windows as it's included as an additional component. There's also [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) which is free.

Comment: damn, haha, thanx